# Anything to fix if accidentally logged out during installation?

Tags: installation, re-installation, ubiquity

I started installing Oneiric, with whatever option keeps your files but upgrades the OS (don't remember what it's called any more). It got to the part when it is running apt-clone to restore previously installed packages, but during the middle of that, I accidentally logged out of the LiveCD session. Is there anything that the installer does after that that I need to do manually now? Is it fine? Should I just reinstall over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Just restart the computer and run the install package again. I did the same thing trying to update

Comment: That's kinda what I figured (and what I did eventually). I'll leave this open a few more days and see if anyone can tell us what to do next time; then I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: Okay. I did the same thing. Well, kinda. I was updating to 11.04 and I forgot I was on battery power...